How to have lastpass work with my website's registration page?
LastPass on my website's registration page is not acknowledging the email field.
<form @submit.prevent="registerUser">
    <input v-model="email" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="" />
<button
                            class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-12 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            type="submit" :disabled="registerButtonDisabled">
                            <span v-if="!registerButtonDisabled">Register</span>
                            <div v-else class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                                <svg class="animate-spin h-5 w-5 text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                    fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <circle class="opacity-25" cx="12" cy="12" r="10" stroke="currentColor"
                                        stroke-width="4"></circle>
                                    <path class="opacity-75" fill="currentColor"
                                        d="M4 12a8 8 0 018-8v4a4 4 0 100 8v4a8 8 0 01-8-8z"></path>
                                </svg>
                                <span>Loading...</span>
                            </div>
                        </button>
</form>


Is your input element inside a ? Are you testing this on localhost (dev environment)?

yes to both....

Judging by the first comment it's clear that just a single line of HTML is insufficient to start debugging your problem. Include a complete simple page that demonstrates the problem. Include any JavaScript you're using. And if you see errors on the browser console, include the complete text of those too. This is basic debugging stuff. See [ask]
